# What does the font size documentclass option actually do?

Tags: spacing, fontsize, class-options

When using e.g. the `[12pt]` option for a document class like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

what does (Xe)LaTeX actually do/set?

I noticed that for example a `multicols` environment behaves different whether I use the `[12pt]`, or no such option but a `\fontsize{12pt}{14.5pt}\selectfont` at the beginning of the document, with some spaces around headlines being 1 or 2 pt different. (The value of `14.5pt` I got from `\the\baselineskip` from the original `[12pt]` version).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two major points here:

1. the option loads the file `size12.clo` which sets the lengths and sizes (not just the sizes for `\small` etc., but also paragraph indentation, the skip amount, apparently, a default for the margins, etc.
2. a package can assume font sizes are set that way by convention and look at the global options to make some changes in its own setup.

Comment: some document classes (for example `amsart` and siblings) have the size option code built into the `.cls` file.  however, i know of no latex document class that departs from the basic model of `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\small`, etc., within the provided range of sizes.  (the provided sizes of the ams classes are a superset of the sizes in the basic classes, adding `\Small` and `\SMALL`.)